# Overwrite manifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

Hi stack overflow community

I am developing an app for android. There I have to programm that when the backbutton is pressed, the app is send to the background.

I have done this with **navigator.app.exitApp()**. But I have found out that I get a second instance of the app when I start it new after pressed backbutton.

So I searched and now I want to overwrite the **manifest.xml** (**android:launchMode="singleTask"** instead of singleTop. But everytime when I enter **cordova run android** to put the app on my phone, the **manifest.xml** will be overwritten (again **singleTop** instead of the **singleTask** which I want.

How I can resolve this overwriting? Is it possible to resolve?
I've heard it is/was a bug of cordova? Have they corrected it?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4911

Ok. What I did so far?
With Notepadd++ I opened the manifest.xml and overwrite the android:launchMode. Then I saved the file and opened the CLI in which I build android or run android.
But everytime these commands have overwritten the manifest.xml file.

Is there another way to modify the file manifest.xml without overwriting?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **navigator.app.exitApp()** you can use **moveTaskToBack()** but I'm not sure if it exists in cordova.

Also I think you set the wrong parameters because you have to set **launchMode** instead of **label**.

```
android:label="Name of the current activity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sry, I wrote android:label instead of android:launchMode. But it is  correctly written in my manifest.xml.
The method moveTaskBack() didn't help. But thanks for the tipp. :P